# Creating a custom uidatepicker - it takes up too much space!

Tags: iphone, xcode, uidatepicker

I would LOOOOVE to have the use of a UIDatePicker that is just one row displayed instead of three.
 
Three rows take up way too much real-estate!
 
HELP!!!
 
I am able to rotate and resize the control without any great stress, but have yet to figure out how to only display the one row. This is not what I'm chasing right this moment.

Any direction would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

The standard pickers are all that big. No way to change this behavior. Although you could place other components on top of it, this would probably not look great, and it's hard to use, as you need *height* to operate the wheels.

Reducing the standard picker to one row would also irritate users, and it *could* be problematic in the review process.

So if you need a one-line-date-picker view, you have to roll your own.

Comment: Do you think it really would irritate users? You know what date/time follows or proceeds the next? Hmmm... Thanks for the comment ;)

Comment: I know the order of dates, but I don't know how to use that one-line control ;-)

Comment: The same way you use the other control but it takes less space ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that using a 1-dimensional picker for date would irritate users or give your problems in the review process. But you will have to do your own date picker by defining your own behavior to a [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. You can use a UIPicker to create a datepicker. Implementation can be found here. https://kmdarshan.wordpress.com/2015/05/03/creating-a-ios-type-date-picker-with-custom-text-in-it/